# I'm just trying to understand the difference between AWS and a smaller site like siteground. How does it interact with an actual website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hosting, cpanel

I think we're using S3 but I'll be sure in a couple of hours when I get into office. I'm just trying to understand the difference between AWS and a smaller site like siteground. How does it interact with an actual website. I am used to cpanel and FTP and having a whole bunch of utilities to work off of. But I don't see much support on AWS and I just want to understand the differences at this point. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Siteground will provide you a pre-installed environment for your website set up,  either for dynamic(php) or static files(html).  where AWS S3 will only allow you to host static files,  you may install your own web server in ec2. You might face issue while setting web server with AWS EC2.

For Comparison between both  of them, you can check this article [Amazon Web Services (AWS) vs. SiteGround](https://hostadvice.com/tools/web-hosting-comparison/amazon-cloudfront-vs-siteground/)

Thanks :)